# AWS Lambda - C# - Environment Variables only load null

Tags: c#, configuration, aws-lambda

-Using Visual Studio 2017-
I am having trouble reading any configuration for a database connection string for my function to consume.
Most information I come across says to use Environment Variables, but I seem to be doing that wrong, or there is missing information.
If I hard-code the connection string in it works without trouble.
Both

```
var value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConStr");
```

and any variation of

```
var value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConStr",EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine/Process/User);
```

only return me null values.

I have configured the variable in the aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json as directed by most sources

```
{
    "Information" : [blah],
    "profile"     : "****",
    "region"      : "****",
    "configuration" : "****",
    "framework"     : "netcoreapp2.1",
    "function-runtime" : "dotnetcore2.1",
    "function-memory-size" : 256,
    "function-timeout"     : 30,
    "function-handler"     : "****::****:****/****/****",
    "function-name"        : "arn:aws****:****/****/****",
    "function-role"        : "****",
    "tracing-mode"         : "PassThrough",
    "environment-variables" : "ConStr=FooBar;",
    "function-description"  : ""
}
```

I can see the value populate in the publish profile when uploading. I can see the values uploaded properly to AWS Lambda through the console. All instances still fail to access the data.

Several sources also talk about a 'Serverless.template' file that I can not find in my files, and no full example is given. Is this what I'm missing? If so can someone break down how to implement that?

Comment: Well If anyone's even paying attention I finally found 'Serverless.template'
in Visual Studio Right click on the project -> add -> ServerlessTempalte